# How to use function-like import proposal feature in Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I want to use [the `import()` feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

I included `stage-2` preset in my project but got the error (during webpack bundling): `Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

What's wrong? How can I use this feature?

Comment: Can you provide some code? I guess you are using it inside of some closure

Comment: webpack supports something similar with [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#commonjs-require-ensure), although is callback based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two Babel transforms to address this feature, depending on your build system.

For Node itself, you'd want to use https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node to use normal `require` calls.

For Webpack 1.x, you'd want to use https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack since it will use Webpack's `require.ensure`.

For Webpack 2.x, `import()` support is included in Webpack, so you'd want to use `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` so Babel will parse and pass through the syntax unchanged to Webpack.

Comment: webpack 2 supports `import()` out of the box